# Set GUID Programatically for New Audience

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, audience-targeting, audiences

I am Creating  **New Audience** programmatically but I want to set its **GUID** by code (my own)

Is it possible to do this ? if yes then how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AudienceID is an internal field set by SharePoint. You can't set it, but you can retrieve it if it has been saved to the db.

What is your requirement that means you have to control the audience ID? Typically you would retrieve Audience by name. If you need to you can then access the AudienceID value.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is it Possible to Assign our own GUID ?

Comment: Unfortunately not - What are you ultimately trying to achieve? Perhaps there is another way to satisfy your requirement.

Comment: can you explain how it is possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Please refer link below link Mr. Raju

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/da/sharepoint2010programming/thread/181fdb91-b16d-4e51-a9a4-454c8ad1c374

You will find that it is not possible because SharePoint manages GUID internally. so you can not assign it. in some cases it is possible but in your case it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this. I created a custom stored procedure (by copying and modifying the one used by the API to create audiences) to create the audience with the GUID I needed. Look at the ORGLE procs inside the Profile DB to see how this is done.

Anyways, once I created the audiences with the proc. I used central admin to configure the rules.

In general, messing with SharePoint databases is not recommended. Be careful in doing this. Its always better to use the API. That being said, this worked out great. No issues. Well tested.

Code:

```
--Created by James Hodges 10-19-2012
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_AddAudience_Custom]    Script Date: 10/19/2012 08:52:19 ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[usp_AddAudience_Custom]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_AddAudience_Custom]
GO


/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_AddAudience_Custom]    Script Date: 10/19/2012 08:52:19 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_AddAudience_Custom]
@AudienceID uniqueidentifier,
@OrgleName nvarchar(500),
@OrgleDescription nvarchar(1500) = NULL

AS

DECLARE
@correlationId uniqueidentifier,
@OrgleID uniqueidentifier,
@Error int,
@srError int,
@GroupType smallint,
@bRemove bit,
@OwnerAccountName nvarchar(400),
@partitionID uniqueidentifier

SET NOCOUNT ON

SET @correlationId = NEWID()
SET @GroupType = 2
SET @bRemove = 0
SET @OwnerAccountName = NULL
SET @partitionID = (SELECT TOP 1 PartitionID FROM Orgle_List WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE OrgleID = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')  --JRH ..This worked for my company. If you have more than one partition you may need to edit this.


SELECT @Error = 1
--check the OrgleID: Note: we make the Audience Name unique across the board.
SELECT @OrgleID = OrgleID FROM Orgle_List WHERE OrgleName = @OrgleName AND PartitionID = @partitionID

IF @bRemove = 1
BEGIN
    IF @OrgleID IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        EXEC @Error =  Orgle_RemoveOrgle @partitionID, @OrgleID, @correlationId=@correlationId
    END
END
ELSE  -- add a new one
BEGIN
    SELECT @Error = 3

    IF @OrgleID IS NOT NULL -- can't create a duplicate orgle name
        GOTO CODE_EXIT

    SET @Error = 0
    BEGIN
        -- create the new orgle name
        SELECT @OrgleID = @AudienceID
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Orgle_List ( PartitionID, OrgleID, OrgleName, OrgleNameDescription, OwnerAccountName )
                VALUES ( @partitionID, @OrgleID, @OrgleName, @OrgleDescription, @OwnerAccountName )

            IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
            BEGIN
                -- insert into stats
                DECLARE @UpdateTime as DATETIME
                    SET @UpdateTime = GETUTCDATE()
                -- insert into stats
                INSERT INTO Orgle_Stats 
                    (PartitionID, OrgleID, GroupType, CreateTime, LastPropertyUpdate, QueryCOunt, GroupCount, MembershipCount, OrgleLock) 
                    VALUES (@partitionID, @OrgleID, @GroupType, @UpdateTime, @UpdateTime, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 1
                SET @Error = 3  
            END
            ELSE
                SET @Error = 3
        END
        IF @Error = 0
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
        ELSE
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END

END

CODE_EXIT:
    SELECT @Error AS ERROR, @OrgleID AS OrgleID

SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

Comment: This is [unsupported](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841057).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the audience GUID in audience rule  ..

```
$newrule = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Audience.AudienceRuleComponent($property,"Not Contains","GUID");
[Void]$newaud.AudienceRules.Add($newrule);
```