# How to create target audience with GUID via PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, user-profile-service, audience-targeting

I am creating target audience using the sample code here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/create-an-audience-for-sharepoint-server

My problem is that when I create target audiences in different environments they get created with different GUIDs.

Is there a way to create a target audience with a specific GUID?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think we can set the GUID for audience by ourselves.

AudienceID is automatically generated by SharePoint and it is stored in database. It is unsupported to modify the database directly.

Similar thread:

[Set GUID Programatically for New Audience](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47676/set-guid-programatically-for-new-audience)